# CSS changes are not being applied in frontend

Tags: css

We would like to enter the text "Want more? Call Today 02089110265" in a box.

We have added css to the `override.css`,  but when we uploaded the file the changes not showing in the website.

Can anybody help us and let u know where we done something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the changes are not being reflected in the front end:

- Make sure you have modified the correct file
- Clear your Magento cache
- Clear your browser cache (CTRL+F5) on your keyboard
- Try a different web browser

If you are still having trouble, use firefox with firebug (or similar) find the appropriate `css` and make the changes lives to get the result you want and note the correct file to modify and upload the changes.

*Also note, depending on the theme, usually it is `custom.css` that you need to enter the code.*

Comment: No problem, if this resolved your issue please use the check mark to select as the correct answer. if you want you can upvote it as well. Thanks